# ALTER table column name in stored function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I'm working with the following function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION TestFunc (@year INT)
RETURNS @RetTable TABLE(
    Forename VARCHAR(32),
    Lastname VARCHAR(32),
    Course1 INT,
    Course2 INT,
    Course3 INT
)
```

In the body of the function I'm declaring various variables such as:

```
DECLARE @CourseOne VARCHAR(12);
DECLARE @CourseTwo VARCHAR(12);
DECLARE @CouseThree VARCHAR(12);
```

I then want to use these variables in order to apply another column name as following:

```
INSERT INTO @RetTable SELECT Forename, Lastname, C1 AS @CourseOne, C2 AS @CourseTwo, C3 AS @CourseThree FROM Teachers
```

The problem in this case is that the column name will still be "*Course1, Course2, Course3*" even though I tried to "rename" the columns in the **INSERT**

Is there any way to make this work or is there any other way I could tackle this problem?

Comment: You can't change the column name of a table... its set when you define it.

Comment: Alright. Do you have any good suggestion on how I could achive the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Why do you want to change the column names?

Comment: I need the colum-names to be dynamic due to an application that I'm working on. The function will be called from C#-Winforms and inserted directly into a Dataset, So I would like to set the names in the database before returning the table if possible.

Comment: Rename the columns in the `SELECT` that selects from that function.

Comment: That seems an odd design, why not just make the columns names static in your app? Or have multiple specific functions to deal with each case? T-SQL is not ideal for trying to make generic code solutions, its works much better when you are specific. If you still think this is the best solution then you'll need to use a stored procedure.

Comment: @stickybit, That would leave me in the same position but in another place. The renaming process still needs to be dynamic, so not sure if that would work.

Comment: The renaming process in your app is easy... because your query is just a string at that point, so you can build the string however you want.

Comment: You can build the query dynamically in the C# code with whatever aliases.

Comment: @DaleK, Thanks Dale! I'll try to tackle this problem from another angle then.

Comment: This has all the markings of an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would be better if you took a step back, figure out that problem you're trying to solve, and then ask the correct question. from what you've described in the comments, this seems like something that should be handled on the display side of the application, and only there.

Comment: I agree with you @ZoharPeled, It's probably better to do it on the app-side. 
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rename the columns in the table.  Why do you want to rename columns in the middle of a function?

You could rename them when you call the function

```
SELECT Forename, Lastname, Course1 AS CourseOne, Course2 AS CourseTwo,Course3 AS Course3
FROM TestFunc(@year)
```

OR you could change your function declaration to have the tables named CourseOne, etc. at the start